# How to manage multiple sequential subscribe methods in Angular and RxJs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to call two http service calls and subscribe them after subscribing another one http service call. I mean, the operation will be sequential as the last two calls depend on the first one. Can this operation be handled with concatMap of RxJs?

I solved the problem using nested subscription. But, I think using concatMap, this can be done. In all examples I searched, there are two calls which are concatenated. How to concat more than two subscription and solve the issue.

```
this.accountService.fetchBranchCodeLength().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.branchCodeLength = +data;


    //Now, I need to call another service to calculate 
    accountNumberLengthWithProductCode//


   this.subscribers.fetchAcoountNumberLength = 
    this.accountService.fetchAccountLengthConfiguration().subscribe(
      accountLength => {
        this.accountNumberLengthWithProductCode = 
            (+accountLength) - (+this.branchCodeLength);});


    //Another same kind of call to calculate 
    SUBGLCodeLength//


   this.subscribers.fetchSUBGLCodeLengthSub = 
     this.glAccountService.fetchSUBGlCodeLength(SUBGlCodeQueryParam)
      .subscribe(length => this.SUBGLCodeLength = 
          (+length.value) - (+this.branchCodeLength)                        
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `concatMap`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651060/how-to-use-rxjs-observables-in-sequential-order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use RxJS observables in sequential order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651060/how-to-use-rxjs-observables-in-sequential-order)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 combine three http calls with flatMap? RxJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698649/angular-2-combine-three-http-calls-with-flatmap-rxjs)

Comment: According to your links, I've changed the code like this but how to call another service now? 

this.subscribers.fetchBranchCodeLengthSub = 
   this.accountService.fetchBranchCodeLength().pipe(
            concatMap(data =>
                this.accountService.fetchAccountLengthConfiguration().pipe(
                    map(accountLength => {
                        this.accountNumberLengthWithProductCode = 
                          (+accountLength) - (+data);
                  })
                )
            )
        ).subscribe();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concat map is used when you have a lot of requests, but when they are similar, it means they will have the same output data and handler, which is not your case. So you can use **forkJoin**, because there are no any dependencies among your calls.

### Code

```
forkJoin(
   this.accountService.fetchBranchCodeLength(),
   this.accountService.fetchAccountLengthConfiguration(),
   this.glAccountService.fetchSUBGlCodeLength(SUBGlCodeQueryParam)
).subscribe(([data, accountLength, length]) => {
   this.branchCodeLength = +data;
   this.accountNumberLengthWithProductCode = (+accountLength) - this.branchCodeLength
   this.SUBGLCodeLength = (+length.value) - this.branchCodeLength;
});
```

---

And by the way, you do not need to unsubscribe from http call observables, because they are finite (to be precise the emit only one event).

Comment: forkJoin will do the task easily. Great Solution :) 

Can I know how to do that by concatMap. Like you said when there are a lot of requests, how to handle them? 

And I think if you don't unsubscribe when we destroy and recreate our components but we don’t clean up existing subscriptions this subscription remains and cause the memory leak. 

Got from this link: https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. About unsubscription take a look on that article https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3, about concatMap you can think about it as a **for** loop, so you need to perform same action for **N** identical observables, but you run them sequentially one after antoher https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293.

Comment: But sometimes it is needed. See the comment of your linked article- 
https://medium.com/@viktorlove/its-not-very-correct-to-say-that-you-don-t-need-to-unsubscribe-on-http-requests-58174024ea54

Comment: Oh, yeah, that is true, when situation like "your component destroys earlier than you get response from server" is possible then unsubsribe can be useful.

Comment: And from your article of ConcatMap, there is a warning for using forkJoin- 
See forkJoin() caveat part.